Export Image with excel sheet in Laravel failed
In Laravel project I try to include the img from database that store in LongBlob data type in exported excel sheet, but It does not work fine, where the image appear as text as showen in the attached following image
photo apear in excel as this
This code to save a photo
$photo = $req->file('pic_of_transfer');
$photoData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($photo->getRealPath()));
$invoice->pic_of_transfer = $photoData;

This code to export excel sheet
namespace App\Exports;
use App\Models\invoice;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use App\Models\Report;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\StringHelper;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Drawing as SharedDrawing;
class excelInvoiceRecords implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    protected $records;
    
    public function __construct($records)
    {
        $this->records = $records;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return collect($this->records)->map(function ($record) {
            return [
                $this->getBase64Image($record->pic_of_transfer), // Get Base64 image data
                $record->invoice_issuer,
                $record->issuance_date,
                $record->total,
                $record->network_paid_amount + $record->cash_paid_amount + $record->transfer_paid_amount,
                $record->payment_method,
                $record->discount,
                $record->tax_percentage,
                $record->fees_with_tax,
                $record->fees_without_tax,
                $record->invoice_type,
                $record->id,
            ];
        });
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'مرفقات الفاتورة',
            'الموظف المُصدر الفاتورة',
            'تاريخ إصدار الفاتورة',
            'إجمالي الفاتورة',
            'المدفوع',
            'طريقة الدفع',
            'الخصم الإضافي',
            'نسبة الضريبة المُضافة',
            'الرسوم مع ضريبة',
            'الرسوم بدون ضريبة',
            'نوع الفاتورة',
            'رقم الفاتورة',
        ];
    }

    protected function getBase64Image($imageData)
    {
        // Decode Base64 image data
        $decodedImage = base64_decode($imageData);
        
        // Save the decoded image to a temporary file
        $tempImagePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'excel_image');
        file_put_contents($tempImagePath, $decodedImage);
        
        // Get the MIME type of the image
        $mimeType = mime_content_type($tempImagePath);

        // Read the image file into a string
        $imageData = file_get_contents($tempImagePath);

        // Delete the temporary file
        unlink($tempImagePath);

        // Encode the image data as Base64
        $base64Image = 'data:' . $mimeType . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imageData);

        return $base64Image;
    }
}

This is in controller to do the exporting
$file = new excelInvoiceRecords($records);
return Excel::download($file, 'Invoice reports.xlsx');

What is the wrong, how can I solve that ..

You are passing base64 encoded string to excel, that's why it shows only the encoded string and not the image.
Each image should be added as "drawing". First, save blob as image(this part is correnct in your code) and then pass the image path to the drawing class.
Example from documentation:
public function drawings()
{
    $drawing = new Drawing();
    $drawing->setName('Logo');
    $drawing->setDescription('This is my logo');
    $drawing->setPath(public_path('/img/logo.jpg'));
    $drawing->setHeight(90);
    $drawing->setCoordinates('B3');

    return $drawing;
}


I get this error Object of class PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing could not be converted to string
